# How to Print a Text Under the Barcode in c#

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

I have a radgridview in which I am displaying a barcode now I want to print the BarCode I such a way that the text appears under the BarCode and each BarCode should come on a single page. I used the Free 3 of 9 font to display the BarCode into the radgridview but now I do not know how to print that BarCode on a separate page as well as in a described above.

RadGridView, I am generating using Free 3 of 9

[image]

Now I want to print this in the following format

[image]

Either I have to remove the borders of the radgridview and display it in such a way that the column 1 should be on the top of column 2 and these both exists on the same page , For next row I have to use the other page.

Or else I have to do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Code39, its perfect solution to your problem